# playframework scala how to flat a Future[Seq[Seq[Int]]

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I have the following code:

```
val f0: Future[Seq[Seq[Int]]] = processPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessPrerequisiteIdsByProcessTemplateId(processTemplateId).flatMap(pres =>
  Future.sequence(
    pres.map(pre =>
      processPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessPrerequisiteProcessTemplateIdsByProcessTemplateId(pre)
    ))
)
```

How can I flat one Seq? The Future should be kept.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `map` on the `Future` and flatten the `Seq[Seq[Int]]`:

```
val flattened = f0.map(_.flatten)
// Future[Seq[Int]]
```